# Is it possible to remotely get IMEI for a usb connected Symbian cellphone, on Windows?

Tags: symbian, imei

If I connected a Symbian cellphone to PC via usb, is there any way to remotely and programmatically read IMEI.
Nokia Ovi Suite can read it but I didn't see any public APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most simple Nokia phones you can do this by sending `AT+CGSN\r\n` on the serial port of the modem of the phone. However if I remember well on smartphones Nokia disabled this feature for some reason. Anyhow it worth a try. Here's a nice tutorial on how to do this: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/AT_Commands

Comment: I've tried AT commands. As you said, it worked. However, I didn't make myself clear, I need a way to programmatically read IMEI on Windows, but I don't know to do it with AT commands and hyper terminal.

Comment: It's just an emulated serial port what you can open and write to it from a program. Check out windows serial port APIs (I don't know them at all). The only tricky thing might be to find on which serial port the phone is on, but there might be some helpful functions for also this in the APIs